# jQuery refesh on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of jQuery which changes the text in a div called #myQuote when I reload/refresh the page. I also want to have a link next to it you can press to refresh the text. I have called the link id="requote" I want it so when this is clicked it changes the text similar to when page is refreshed.

Here is the jQuery I have so far:

```
var myQuotes = new Array();
myQuotes[0] = "Quote One";
myQuotes[1] = "Quote Two";
myQuotes[2] = "Quote Three";
myQuotes[3] = "Quote Four";

var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length);

$('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: try `.text` instead of `.html`

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = $("#requote");
link.on("click", function(){
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length);
  $("some.div").html(myQuotes[random]);
  // prevent default behaviour
  return false;
});
```

Comment: First time lucky. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#requote").click(function(){
  var myQuotes = new Array();
  myQuotes[0] = "Quote One";
  myQuotes[1] = "Quote Two";
  myQuotes[2] = "Quote Three";
  myQuotes[3] = "Quote Four";

  var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length);

  $('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#requote").on("click", function() {
  //helper code
  $('#myQuote').text(<your string>);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#reqoute').click(function(){
 $('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);
});
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

After this

```
 $('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);

 $(document).on('click', '#requote', function() {
      $('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {

    var myQuotes = new Array();
    myQuotes[0] = "Quote One";
    myQuotes[1] = "Quote Two";
    myQuotes[2] = "Quote Three";
    myQuotes[3] = "Quote Four";

    //var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length);

    var myRandom = myQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length)];
    //console.log(myRandom);

    $('#myQuote').text(myRandom);

    $('#refresh_link').click(function()
    {
        var myRandom = myQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length)];

        $('#myQuote').text(myRandom);

    });

});


</script>


<div id='myQuote'></div><a id ="refresh_link" href="#">click to refresh</a>
```